# Android Custom ActionBar with Search View

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat

I am using custom ActionBar library in my Android App. there i want to show a searchView but can not find any solution, i m working in library that is 
https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar


This is a class

```
private class ExampleAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ExampleAction() {
            super(R.drawable.ic_title_export_default);
        }

        @Override
        public void performAction(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(OtherActivity.this, "Example action",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    //use for signle action how to use for multiactions
       ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
       actionBar.addAction(new ExampleAction());
```

actually i found code for searchbar but it is in .cs format how to use this searchview 

https://github.com/zleao/MonoDroid.ActionBar

Thanks bro & sis

Comment: you can use searchable from android http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html it will just replace your custom view in `ActionBar` when `Intent` with actions `SEARCH` is requested

Comment: thanks bro, it require api level 11 but i am working on api level 8. so we need like above we mention.

Comment: You need to use support library for backward compatibility

Comment: actionBar.addAction(new Action() {
   Override
   public void performAction(View view) {
    Toast.makeText(Main.this, "Added action1. ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
      .show();
   }

   Override
   public int getDrawable() {
    return R.drawable.ic_title_share_default;
   }
  });

now i used this method it work fine for me..
thanks @Yurets

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18288724/searchview-on-support-v7-appcompat-library-issue-default-9-patch-background-not).
According to this answer `SearchView` is available support library.
add dependency to `build.gradle`

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
```

and make imports

`import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
 import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;`

According to this answer it worked on API 8 on emulator. For more details, check the link with the question and answer itself.
Hope it helps.

**UPDATE**

By adding this code

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:hmkcode="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    hmkcode:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_copy"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    hmkcode:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_content_copy"
    android:title="Copy"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_share"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    hmkcode:showAsAction="always"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_social_share"
    android:title="Share"/>
```

you can achieve this:

[image]

You can customize items in the way you want. For more details see this [example](http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/).

Comment: @AttaullahKhan, I updated answer, take a look. I think it looks similar to your request. And I found one more similar example, http://antonioleiva.com/actionbarcompat-how-to-use/ , so I think it relies on the way you customize items, question is not about compatibility anymore, so if you satisfied with the way to achieve compatibility on API 8, please accept the answer and question will be closed.

Comment: i used my own mention library, but this also work fine for me, thanks
@Yurets

Comment: but search view still not work in example
[link](http://hmkcode.com/add-actionbar-to-android-2-3-x/)

Comment: you should customize the behavior in `onItemMenuSelected` by yourself, this is an example how to achieve what you showed on the picture before.