# how to create custome actionbar for an activity

Tags: android, android-actionbar

working on application in which i need a custom action bar try appcompat_v7 also 
but did not work for me any idea.

my code is

```
private class ExampleAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ExampleAction() {
            super(R.drawable.ic_title_export_default);
        }

        @Override
        public void performAction(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(OtherActivity.this, "Example action",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    //use for signle action how to use for multiactions
```

how to call to call actionbar for any view

Comment: you can define the custom style and can provide it to activity in manifest

Comment: This question is already solve and same like this try this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815192/android-custom-actionbar-with-search-view) hope it help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is already solve and same like this try this [**link**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815192/android-custom-actionbar-with-search-view) hope it help you

```
private class ExampleAction extends AbstractAction {

        public ExampleAction() {
            super(R.drawable.ic_title_export_default);
        }

        @Override
        public void performAction(View view) {
            Toast.makeText(OtherActivity.this, "Example action",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
    //use for signle action how to use for multiactions
       ActionBar actionBar = (ActionBar) findViewById(R.id.actionbar);
       actionBar.addAction(new ExampleAction());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to go with Android's **Toolbar** which is replacement of ActionBar introduced in Android 5.0 and it also has backward compatibility. Check below links.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

http://javatechig.com/android/android-lollipop-toolbar-example

http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-material-design-v7-appcompat/

Answer (score 0):

You can design custom actionBar like this:

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#2B1C27")));

    LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.titleview_2, null);

    TextView actionbar_title = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.actionbar_title);
    actionbar_title.setTypeface(youcanset your font here also.);

    actionBar.setCustomView(v);
```

and in xml file try something like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/actionBar"
android:paddingTop="7dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:background="#9B66AB">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/actionbar_title"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:text="@string/appTitle"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:background="@mipmap/logo"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/actionbar_title" />
```

Hope it helps ... :)

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to Use toolbar to customize Action bar, have a look at these links.
[this tutorial 1](http://blog.xamarin.com/android-tips-hello-toolbar-goodbye-action-bar/) [tutorial 2](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)
and here is a simple [Project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-android/tree/master/Menus/ActionBarBC)