# Android. How to add button to the bottom (navigation bar)

Tags: android, user-interface

I want to add a button to navigation bar to the right of BACK, HOME, APP STACK buttons (like in Viber app-n: when begin typing little icon of keyboard appears). Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Action Bar Button if yes then try **[this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29815192/android-custom-actionbar-with-search-view?noredirect=1#comment47758063_29815192)**

you say Viber like when begin typing: there TextWatcher class is use **[see example](http://javatechig.com/android/android-textwatcher-example)**